# Synology Surveillance Web API Authentication in HTML?

Tags: html, api, synology

I am trying to connect to my Synology Surveillance Station and feed a cam "snapshot" to a web page. If I enter this into my browser

```
http://MyNASip:5000/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=1&account=USERNAME&passwd=PASSWORD&session=SurveillanceStation
```

it authenticates. Then I can enter this into my browser

```
http://MyNASip:5000/webapi/entry.cgi?camStm=1&version="8"&cameraId=1&api="SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera"&preview=true&method="GetSnapshot"
```

and it will give me a snapshot.

How can I get my html to authenticate?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <img src='http://MyNASip:5000/webapi/entry.cgi?camStm=1&version="8"&cameraId=1&api="SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera"&preview=true&method="GetSnapshot"' 
    />

</body>
</html>
```

This will just fail?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read about how to send API requests using cURL. Search depending on your programming language (e.g. [cURL in php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)).
Once you have a cURL lib to use, first authenticate and then fetch the snapshot, and create this way your img in html.
Hope this point you in the right direction.